# Unable to connect localhost when using eventflux library

Tags: flutter

Currently I just try to explore the server sent event method. For frontend, I am using flutter and backend using `golang`. When I try to connect server in flutter side, it return error. Is there any setup wrongly?

Error:

```
Error connecting to EventFlux: Instance of 'EventFluxException'
I/flutter ( 9445): Exception details: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 38134, uri=http://localhost:8080/events
```

Flutter code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:eventflux/client.dart';
import 'package:eventflux/enum.dart';
import 'package:eventflux/eventflux.dart';
import 'package:eventflux/models/data.dart';
import 'package:eventflux/models/response.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_client_sse/constants/sse_request_type_enum.dart';
import 'package:flutter_client_sse/flutter_client_sse.dart';
import 'package:sse_stream/sse_stream.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter EventFlux Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final EventFlux _eventFlux = EventFlux.instance;

  String _receivedData = "";
  final dio = Dio();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _connectToEventFlux();
  }


  void _connectToEventFlux() {
    _eventFlux.connect(
      EventFluxConnectionType.get,
      'http://localhost:8080/events',
      onSuccessCallback: (EventFluxResponse? response) {
        response!.stream?.listen((data) {
          // Update the UI with the received data
          setState(() {
            // Assuming your data is a string, you can update it accordingly
            // For example, you can store the data in a variable to use in the UI

            _receivedData = data.toString();
          });
        });
      },
      onError: (error) {
        // Handle errors
        print('Error connecting to EventFlux: $error');
        // Print more details about the exception if available
        print('Exception details: ${error.message}');
      },
      autoReconnect: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter EventFlux Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Display the received data in the UI
            Text(
              'Received Data:',
            ),
            Text(
              _receivedData,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _eventFlux.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you run the Flutter code from ? and where the Go code running from ?.

If you are running Flutter code inside emulator, and the Go is running from Host machine. The answer is Host your Go throught IP address, then consume it also from the flutter using IP address not localhost.

```
void _connectToEventFlux() {
_eventFlux.connect(
  EventFluxConnectionType.get,
  'http://192.168.x.xxx:8080/events'
  // 'http://localhost:8080/events',
  onSuccessCallback: (EventFluxResponse? response) {
    response!.stream?.listen((data) {
      // Update the UI with the received data
      setState(() {
        // Assuming your data is a string, you can update it accordingly
        // For example, you can store the data in a variable to use in the UI

        _receivedData = data.toString();
      });
    });
  },
  onError: (error) {
    // Handle errors
    print('Error connecting to EventFlux: $error');
    // Print more details about the exception if available
    print('Exception details: ${error.message}');
  },
  autoReconnect: true,
);
```

}